# Question about some symbols in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, notation

I'm tring to understand some symbols in physics formula
for example in Ehrenfest’s theorem

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\langle \hat Q \rangle = \left\langle \frac{\partial \hat Q}{\partial t} \right\rangle +\frac{i}{\hbar}\langle[\hat H,\hat Q]\rangle $$

I think Q and H with hat represent operator, but what's the symbol "< >" and "[a, b]" mean here?

Comment: Hi Hugo, I've edited your question to use MathJax rather than an image of an equation.  Please do this in the future - you can find a guide on basic MathJax syntax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"$\langle\hat{Q}\rangle$" Stands for average values of some operator $\hat{Q}$ $$\langle \hat{Q}\rangle = \frac{\langle \psi|\hat{Q}| \psi\rangle}{\langle \psi|\psi\rangle}. $$

$[\hat{Q},\hat{P}]$ is the commutation of operators $\hat{P} ,\hat{Q}$ defined as

$$[\hat{Q},\hat{P}] = \hat{Q}\hat{P} - \hat{P}\hat{Q}. $$

Comment: Thanks for help, in ${\langle \psi|\hat{Q}| \psi\rangle}$ oprrator been put in the middle of braket, what is the meaning of this form

Comment: That is the inner product, $\langle \Psi | \hat{Q}| \Psi\rangle = \int \Psi^* \hat{Q} \Psi \mathrm{d}^3 x$

Comment: now I understand, thanks a lot